# Divide OpportunityLineItem Quantity Schedule Evenly

Tags: trigger, opportunity-lineitem, opportunitylineitemschedule

I have a requirement where we need to insert OLIQuantity Schedule automatically. I need to divide the quantity evenly to the duration given. Like if `Duration = 3` and `productQuantity = 11`, i need to divide it 3,3,4. The last installment should have the reminder.

```
Integer newQuantity = Integer.ValueOf(productQuantity)/Duration;
for(Integer count=0; count<Duration; count++)
    {

    OpportunityLineItemSchedule OLISchedule = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
    OLISchedule.Quantity = newQuantity


    }
```

Comment: What code did you write to implement the requirements you have specified?. Did you run into any code logic errors?

Comment: I have posted above. I am getting all the same quantity values

Answer (score 0):

You need the **modulo** operation, which yields the remainder after integer division. In Apex, this is done with `Math.mod()` (unlike some other C-family languages where you'll see the `%` operator).

Given Integers `Duration` and `productQuantity`, you wish to divide `productQuantity` into `Duration` segments, where the final segment includes any remainder not evenly divisible. The segments will then be

```
segmentSize = Integer.valueOf(Duration / productQuantity);
finalSegmentSize = segmentSize + Math.mod(Duration, productQuantity);
```

where the `finalSegmentSize` includes the remainder.

You don't need `Integer.valueOf()` because integer divison in Apex already truncates.

You'll need to create `Duration - 1` segments of size `segmentSize` and 1 segment of size `finalSegmentSize`. Note that if `Duration` is evenly divisible by `productQuantity`, the two will be the same, but you don't need to handle that as a special case.